# Can Jetty be configured to serve AWS Certificate Manager certs?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, ssl, jetty, aws-certificate-manager

Running a Java web service with embedded Jetty web container. Would like to serve my RESTful API endpoints over HTTPS with a root CA-signed SSL cert (no OpenSSL).

Can I configure my embedded Jetty container to use a "free" [AWS Certificate Manager cert](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) cert or are those certs only for use by AWS infrastructure (ELB, CloudFormation, etc.)? If so can I assume these certs are root CA-signed?

Basically I'm trying to figure out whether I need to spend a few hundred bucks on a Thawte/GoDaddy cert or if I can get one for free via AWS.

Comment: AWS Certificate manager certs can only be used by ELB, CloudFront and API Gateway. You would have to place an ELB, or a CloudFront distribution in front of your Jetty application in order to use an ACM SSL certificate.

Comment: If you don't want one of the other Amazon services in front of your server you can spend ~USD $10/year from at least NameCheap for a real SSL cert.  I've used them in the past with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Mark's comment:

> "*AWS Certificate manager certs can only be used by ELB, CloudFront and API Gateway. You would have to place an ELB, or a CloudFront distribution in front of your Jetty application in order to use an ACM SSL certificate.*"

So **yes** you can use one of the free AWS root CA-signed certs *if* you put your Jetty-based services behind ELBs.